# Get main RenderPanel from Display

Tags: rviz

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hey,

I need to grab a pointer to rviz main RenderPanel - the one that renders the scene - from a Display plugin.
I've managed to grab a RenderPanel but in some cases there are more than one and I haven't found a way to identify them yet.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/241996/get-main-renderpanel-from-display/) by [StefanFabian](https://answers.ros.org/users/27659/stefanfabian/) on ROS Answers with karma: 46 on 2016-08-18

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Okay, I just accidentally found out how to get it while searching for a way to get the **ViewController**.
You get it as follows:

Your class should have a **DisplayContext *** property called ***context_***.
Through this property we can access the **ViewManager** by calling `context_->getViewManager()` that can give us a reference to the **RenderPanel** by calling `getRenderPanel()`.

So in short to grab the **RenderPanel** you simply call:

`rviz::RenderPanel* panel = context_->getViewManager()->getRenderPanel();`

---

Originally posted by [StefanFabian](https://answers.ros.org/users/27659/stefanfabian/) with karma: 46 on 2016-08-27

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1